# Creating dynamic font-size based on container height: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

**Situation:**

I'm trying to force the text's font-size to be proportional to the container's height, so that it acts like text that is part of the background image. I'm trying that by giving the container a `font-size` in `px` that is 1/20th (approximately for now) of its `height` and then defining the descendant text elements in terms of `em`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="front-page-blue-strip">
    <h1>Here's my title</h1>
    <p>Here's the text under my title</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#front-page-blue-strip h1 { font-size: 1.5em;}
#front-page-blue-strip p  { font-size: 0.9em;}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
      $('#front-page-blue-strip').attr('font-size', ($(this).height() / 20).toString() + 'px');     
});
```

Now I've confirmed that the `font-size` of `#front-page-blue-strip` is being rescaled like planned, but the `font-size` of the inner `h1` and `p` elements is not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `.attr('style', 'font-size:'` instead (or the standard jQuery `.css()` method).

Comment: This `$('#front-page-blue-strip').attr` should be `$('#front-page-blue-strip').css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#front-page-blue-strip').attr('font-size', ($(this).height() / 20).toString() + 'px');
```

By doing this you are simply adding attribute to element which is not predefined
property, rather its a property of one of predefined property `style`.

Instead try this

```
$('#front-page-blue-strip').css('font-size', ($(this).height() / 20).toString() + 'px');
```

or

```
$('#front-page-blue-strip')
 .attr('style','font-size:'+ ($(this).height() / 20).toString() + 'px');
```

Comment: The `$(this)` isn't returning `$('#front-page-blue-strip')`, though. Any idea why that is? I replaced `$('#front-page-blue-strip')` with `$(this)` and it worked. Hmm

Comment: because the context is the containing function, so becomes that context

Answer (score 1):

The `font-size` needs to go inside the `style` attribute. You can do it by using jQuery's [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
      $('#front-page-blue-strip').css('font-size', ($(this).height() / 20).toString() + 'px');     
});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8qb05ho/)